# using variables in $_POST to Query Database

Tags: php

Currently working on a PHP Site, that should Query a Database, based on the selected Value. 
I am able to Select DataCenter and vCenter, But the Select Option for ESXi is show my Error: No Data Available.

If i run the Same program with Datacenter='$datac' removed it works but unable to query the following:

```
  $query1 = "Select ESXIName FROM vsphere.test WHERE Datacenter='$datac' AND Vcenter='$vc' ORDER BY ESXIName ASC";
```

Index.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
include_once 'database.php';
    $query = "Select DISTINCT Datacenter from vsphere.test ORDER BY Datacenter ASC";
    $results = $connect->query($query);
?>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" a href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <form action="" method="post">
    <h3>Enter in Details</h3>
    <!-- Select DataCenter -->
    <div class="box">
        <select required id="datacenter">
            <option value="">Select Datacenter</option>
            <?php
            if ($results->num_rows > 0) 
            {
                while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['Datacenter'].'">'.$row['Datacenter'].'</option>'; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<option value="">Data not available for DataCenter</option>'; 
            }?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Select vCENTER -->
    <div class="box">
        <select required id="vcenter">
            <option value="">Select vCenter</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- Select ESXi -->
    <div class="box">
        <select id="esx">
            <option value="">Select ESXi Host</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <!-- SELECT DATASTORE -->
    <div class="box">
        <select required id="datasource">
            <option value="">Select DataSource </option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="text" name="user" required="required" placeholder="Username" autofocus required></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-item">
        <input type="password" name="pass" required="required" placeholder="Password" required></input>
    </div>

    <div class="button-panel">
        <input type="submit" class="button" title="Log In" name="login" value="Submit"></input>
    </div>
  </form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // DataBase Function Change
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datacenter').on('change', function(){
        var a = document.getElementById("datacenter").value;
        if(a){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'Datacenter='+a,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#vcenter').html(html);
                    $('#esx').html('<option value="">Select ESXi Host</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
    // vCenter Function Chanage
    $('#vcenter').on('change', function(){
        var x = document.getElementById("vcenter").value;
        if(x){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'Vcenter='+x,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#esx').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
});
</script>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Data.php

```
<?php 
// Include the database config file 
include_once 'database.php'; 

if(!empty($_POST["Datacenter"]))
{
    $datac = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['Datacenter']);
    $query = "Select DISTINCT Vcenter FROM vsphere.test WHERE Datacenter='$datac' ORDER BY Vcenter ASC";
    $result = $connect->query($query); 
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    { 
        echo '<option value="">Select vCenter</option>'; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['Vcenter'].'">'.$row['Vcenter'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else
    { 
        echo '<option value="">vcenter not available</option>'; 
    } 

}if(!empty($_POST["Vcenter"]))
{ 
    $datac = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['Datacenter']);
    $vc = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['Vcenter']);
    $query1 = "Select ESXIName FROM vsphere.test WHERE Datacenter='$datac' AND Vcenter='$vc' ORDER BY ESXIName ASC";
    $result1 = $connect->query($query1); 
    if($result1->num_rows > 0)
    { 
        echo '<option value="">Select ESXi Host</option>'; 
        while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()){  
            echo '<option value="'.$row['ESXIName'].'">'.$row['ESXIName'].'</option>'; 
        } 
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">ESXI Data Not Available</option>'; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you have not named the `select`

```
<select required id="vcenter">
```

should be

```
<select name="vcenter" required id="vcenter">
```

All of your form elements should have the `name` attribute, a quick examination shows others missing, like `<select id="esx">`, `<select required id="datacenter">` and `<select required id="datasource">`.

**Warning**

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

**Update**

You're using `onchange` events to trigger the AJAX, so as soon as you change `vcenter`, the AJAX is fired and you're only sending one variable:

```
// vCenter Function Chanage
$('#vcenter').on('change', function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("vcenter").value;
    if(x){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'Vcenter='+x, // ONE VARIABLE, MISSING Datacenter
            success:function(html){
                $('#esx').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

You're only sending data:`'Vcenter='+x` consequently, `$datac` has no value here:

```
if(!empty($_POST["Vcenter"]))
{ 
    $datac = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['Datacenter']);
    $vc = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['Vcenter']);
```

which causes your query to fail. Your previous query, triggered *only* when `datacenter` is changed doesn't fail because it is the only variable in the query.

You can change the AJAX call like this (I am using jQuery to get values):

```
// vCenter Function Chanage
$('#vcenter').on('change', function(){
    var vcenter = $("#vcenter").val();
    var datacenter = $("#datacenter").val()
    if(vcenter){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data { Vcenter: vcenter, Datacenter: datacenter },
            success:function(html){
                $('#esx').html(html);
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

But you have a problem, as soon as `datacenter` is changed it fires off one AJAX request, `vcenter` fires off a different request. You're going to have to find a way to determine if only one or both has changed. That is an entirely different problem.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment, I changed the Select to include name but still not rendering the data

Comment: Which exact query fails @Dave?

Comment: $query1 = 'Select ESXIName FROM vsphere.test WHERE Datacenter = "'.$_POST['Datacenter'].'"  AND Vcenter = "'.$_POST['Vcenter'].'" ORDER BY ESXIName ASC';

Comment: Echo `$vc` just before `$vc = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['Vcenter']);` to make sure you're getting what you expect. You keep changing letter casing, so it makes it a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Ok for Testing: echo $vc displays the vaule I select, but $datac i'm getting '' is seems it's unable to pass the data from datac into ifelse

Comment: So `$datac` is empty?

Comment: You're using `onchange` events, so as soon as you change one, the AJAX is fired and you're only sending one variable depending on which change was fired. Consequently `$datac` has no value when Vcenter is changed. You're only sending `data:'Vcenter='+x,`

Comment: What the best way to senting the data for 'Vcenter' & 'DataCenter' from the vCenter on changed ?

Comment: I am updating my answer.

Comment: is this the correct approach ? data:'Vcenter='+x,
                data: 'Datacenter='+a,

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give name of select input only id there so can't give selected value

You can use like that

```
<select required id="vcenter" name="vcenter">
```